# How to execute Excel cell reference to it´s previous value and change cell color based on the new value

Tags: microsoft-excel

My spreadsheet is monitoring the prices from CoinMarketCap and update dynamically every minute my current portfolio. The idea is to change the color of the particular cell if the value is lower, bigger or equal to the previous status: Equal= yellow, Bigger= green and Lower= red.
With the given Excel rules on conditional formatting it not possible to do this. Does somebody can help ? Any existing VBA code available ? or expamles

Thanks in advance for your help :-) Excel 2016
Jacqu

Comment: For this I can suggest you a solution which comprises VBA & Conditional Formatting. VBA (Macro) will help you to keep track record of Previous value & conditional Format  to Format the current value,,, write me are you comfortable with both?

Comment: Absolutely, unless the cells reacting to the price changes with different colors, I´m happy. The funny thing is, that conditional formatting works only if you type the data manually. For example I also monitoring the % changes on the current portfolio and excel do not support -value- red +value green if you doing dynamic data feed to the cells. Once I use the keyboard, works. Thanks for your help :-) Jacqu

Answer (score 1):

In VB editor Window Double click the Sheet where you are getting Coin Market Updates & Paste this VB script.

*I'm assuming that in Column A you are getting the Updates. Replace the column name in line 6 with other if it differs.*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim newVal As Variant

    If Target.Count > 1 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Intersect(Range("A:A"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    newVal = Target.Value

    Application.Undo

    Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = Target.Value

    Target.Value = newVal

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

**Note,** *as soon Excel update the Values in Column A you get Previous values in adjacent column.*

Please do this,

- Select either entire Column A or required rows.
- Click conditional Formatting command.
- Then hit Highlight Cell Rules.

Then after Format one by one for **Equal to, Greater than & Less than conditions.

**Remember, while Format only select Cell B2 for comparison.**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the script. For an unknown reason, my cells are all in yellow regardless the value of the cell. I was trying to reach you on email but unfortunately, something is wrong with your server. Do have any alternative email address?

Comment: Please Try once again the Mail Id it's authentic, otherwise upload the Data on Cloud preferred is Goggle drive.

Comment: OK, This time email has passed. File attached and email is from Jacques

Comment: OKay give me some time & I'll return to you soon.

Comment: Please feel free to answer anytime.

Comment: Could you help me out on this issue ?